# How can I recover a temp file in virtual memory on Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, virtual-memory

I have a temp file stored in virtual memory by an Aiseesoft Recording app that failed to save to disk that I'm trying to rescue. Where can I find that file so I can save/move it?

Comment: “Virtual memory” as in the (disk) drive?  If that’s the case, it would be in the temp directory which could be wn environment variable specific to the app, `$TMP` or `$TEMP`.   You can check `/var/tmp`  or `/tmp` to start.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "How can I retrieve a temp tile ..."?

Comment: Thanks Allen, your corrections were great. I was forced for other reasons to abandon the temp file, so my issue is moot.